# Setting pre-processor definitions with extconf.rb

Tags: c, ruby, extconf.rb

I'm writing a C extension for Ruby, and I have something like this in the extconf.rb file:

```
if(not have_library('z'))
        $stderr << "Error, could not locate zlib.\n"
        abort "Missing zlib"
end
```

So the installation process aborts if zlib is missing. Instead, since my extension can work with AND without zlib, I would like to do something like the following;

```
if(have_library('z'))
        # do something so that -DHAVE_ZLIB is passed to the compiler
        # when compiling the extension.
end
```

How can I do that?

EDIT: The question is on the comment in the if...end statement: how to add the -DHAVE_ZLIB definition for the compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can rely on checking for a *header* file then [`have_header`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/MakeMakefile.html#method-i-have_header) will define a `HAVE_HEADER_H` macro for you. For example:

```
have_header('zlib.h')
```

will define `HAVE_ZLIB_H`, which you can then refer to in your code.

If this isn’t enough or you need to define a macro for some other reason you can use the `$defs` global:

```
if(have_library('z'))
  $defs << '-DHAVE_ZLIB'
  # Now HAVE_ZLIB will be defined for you to check in your code
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as the following your in `extconf.rb` file

```
$libs = ["-lliba", "-llibb"]
if have_library('z')
  # where $libs is your array of libraries defined
  $libs << "-llibz"
end
```

As you can see [in the api docs for have_library](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Object/have_library), the method `have_library` returns either true or false

Comment: This does not answer my question, but maybe my question was not clear. I'll edit it.

Comment: Updated my answer with clarity